# Just white screen on Android with Cordova

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, npm, phonegap-build

[image]

Just Blank white screeen

console in chrome
[image]

give me solution for this,
already reinstall cordova, node, npm but stil not work

Answer (score 1):

Your onDeviceReady() is not called

Comment: can you give me solution sir, sory im newbie

Comment: Post your index.html and js file here so i can provide solution